# jQuery change span width and height inside anchor link

Tags: jquery, css

How can I modify the width and height of a span that is inside an anchor?

There are two spans inside the `a element` and I need to change the width and height of first span.

Example:

```
<a href="http://www.google.com" id="myId" >
   <span style="width:18px; height:18px;"></span>
   <span></span>
</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a CSS selector with the `:first` filter.

```
$("a span:first").css({
      'display':'block',
      'width':'100px',
      'height':'100px'
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't set the width and height of inline elements (or rather, you can set them but they'll be ignored by the browser), so you need to add:

```
display: inline-block;
```

to the element's style. Then the `width` and `height` properties will take effect.

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/sH3Eu/2/

You might wanna read:

http://quirksmode.org/css/css2/display.html

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
$("#myId:first-child").css("width", 100);
```

notice that span will not get width and height unless you change it from inline to block element.

Answer (score 0):

I actually solved it like this and works fine in all browsers...

```
$('#myId').find('span:first').css({
    width: "28px",
    height: "28px"
});
```